# Fusion 360: How to copy a sketch to an offset plane

Tags: cad

Imagine a platform standing on supports on an inclined surface. The support on the right is higher than the one on the left.

I have already created the sketch of the right-hand support and would like to copy it to the plane of the left-hand support in order to change the height there.
I tried to copy and paste the sketch into a new one on the other plane, but the sketch was mirrored. After I mirrored all geometries in the sketch and removed the old ones, the orientation was correct, but all dimensions were missing.

how can I copy the sketch to the other plane so that it is neither mirrored nor losing dimensions in Fusion 360?

[image: current state of my sketch]

Comment: Isn't there a Fusion 360 forum?